# Two different LAN in one BladeCenter?

Tags: bladecenter, ibm

How to Configure Two different LAN in one BladeCenter Chassis?

Topology: Modem --> Monowall --> BladeCenter Chassis --> BC Switch Module 1 (10.1.10.1) and BC Switch Module 2 (192.168.1.1)

What I want: BC Switch Module 1 --> Blade Slots 1-6 and BC Switch Module 2 --> Blade Slots 7-14

Problem I get: BC Switch Modules 1 and 2 are servicing all blade slots 1-14.

Does anyone know how to accomplish "what I want"?

I read up on VLAN in the, "IBM Eserver BladeCenter Networking Options" redbook, but to no avail; very complicated scheme for such simple task. Is this what needs to be done, if so how would you assign the PVID , etc..?

Comment: What switches are you using in your chassis?

Answer (score 0):

Each switch module has a connection to one Ethernet port on each blade.

You can't just have the switches take over both ports.

What you can do is:

- Hook up each switch to the appropriate network
- Bring down ports 7-14 on switch1 and ports 1-6 on switch2
- This will leave you only one connection per blade and isn't ideal.

or:

- Set up VLANs in the switches. It's worth taking the time to do properly.